# Difference b/w these 2 statements while finding height of binary tree?

Tags: c++, binary-tree

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong here.
I am unable to understand the difference between these 2 statements, while finding the height of binary tree.

```
if (root==NULL)   return -1;
```

and

```
if (root->left==NULL && root->right==NULL)  return 0;
```

The first statement is giving me accurate result but if I use the second one it is throwing this error "Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 2.195 s".

Following is the code :

```
int bstHeight(bstNode* root)
{
    //if (root==NULL)   return -1;
    //if (root->left==NULL && root->right==NULL) return 0;

    else
    {
        int lh = bstHeight(root->left);
        int rh = bstHeight(root->right);
        return (lh>rh)? lh+1:rh+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try give as a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What do you understand about those lines? How would you describe what they do?

Comment: Code I'm working on is [this](https://textuploader.com/18qfi) . Just comment out one of the if statement in bstHeight function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one protects against NULL anywhere, in root directly and indirectly via recursion in left and right.
The second is vulnerable against root being NULL, it potentially derferences a NULL, which plausibly gets you the observed error message.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong . You are saying that it is possible that ROOT can come out to be NULL making ROOT---> Left and ROOT----> Right  undefined , resulting in error . But in this [code](https://textuploader.com/18qfi) can you please tell me where ROOT is coming out to be NULL.

Comment: @spoiicy is difficult to tell without a [mre] but at a guess one of `left` and `right` is null resulting in `root` being null when you recurse

Comment: Thanks guys for solving my problem. After doing a bit of simulation of the recursion there was in fact a NULL value being dereferenced , resulting in program giving error. Once again thank u for helping this noob programmer.

Comment: My pleasure and it is very good to be aware of your own level of experience, but do not be too hard on yourself.

Comment: Please provide the value of root for each of the lines of `main()` in your linked code. That will make pinpointing the problem easier. I guess it should be NULL just before the last line, but that needs to be confirmed and traced back to either the init line or one of the others. Use a debugger for that or generous debug output statement instrumenation.